# Speech language in Windows IOT

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I can't find information about this nor "Windows IOT" category.

Is there any way to install new languages to the speech system in Windows IOT for Raspberry Pi ?

I'm writing an app that should speek french but there is no built-in french speech language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help give you multiple languages on Windows 10 IoT Core:

In summary,

1. Install languages on your Win 7/8/10 machine.
2. Copy from: C:\Windows\Speech_OneCore\Engines\SR\(lang)
3. To Windows IoT: \\minwinpc\C$\Windows\Speech_OneCore\Engines\SR\(lang)
4. Then you can use:

   var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(new Language("(lang)"))

Details here:
(original link (died)): http://paulfasola.fr/en/add-voices-windows-10-iot-core-tts/

(wayback machine link): https://web.archive.org/web/20160908171653/https://paulfasola.fr/en/add-voices-windows-10-iot-core-tts/

Answer (score 0):

FYI, there is an excellent [SpeechTranslator project](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SpeechTranslator) in the [ms-iot samples github repo](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples) which shows how to use the SpeechRecongnizer and SpeechSynthesizer in great detail.  After you follow the steps in Jim's answer, you should be able to set the voice on your Speech Synthesizer using:

```
public static string voiceMatchLanguageCode = "fr";

// select the language 
var voices = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices;
foreach (VoiceInformation voice in voices)
{
    if (voice.Language.Contains(voiceMatchLanguageCode)) 
    {
        synthesizer.Voice = voice;
        break;
    }
 }
```